# last inserted id in Php codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my model I have return below function for get record id

```
function getLastInserted()
{
$query = $this->db->select("MAX(`UserID`)+1 as userid")->get("registeration");
return $query->result();            
}
```

Now I want to pass that ID to  mycontroller for record insertion

```
public function newregistration()
{
if ($this->form_validation->run())
{
$data = array(
'Name' => $this->input->post('Name'),
'MobileNo' => $this->input->post('MobileNo'),
'IMEINumber' => $this->input->post('IMEINumber'),
'City' => $this->input->post('City')
);
$this->adminmodel->insertregistration($data);
}
}
```

Now I want to access model function in controller and pass record id in data function How I do ??

Comment: what you mean by this ***Now I want to pass that ID to mycontroller for record insertion***

Comment: can you share code for insertregistration function?

Comment: public function newregistration()
 {
  
  if ($this->form_validation->run())
  {
   $data = array(
   'UserID'=> $this->adminmodel->getLastInserted(),
   'Name' => $this->input->post('Name'),
   'MobileNo' => $this->input->post('MobileNo'),
   'IMEINumber' => $this->input->post('IMEINumber'),
   'City' => $this->input->post('City')
   );
   $this->adminmodel->insertregistration($data);
  }
  
  
 }

Answer (score 1):

set return in model and in controller write

$insert_id=$this->db->insert_id();

Answer (score 0):

In Controller load your model first using

```
$this->load->model('model_name');
```

Then call to model's getLastInserted() function.

```
$ID = $this->model_name->getLastInserted();//you will get id here
```

In model  `return $query->row()->userid;` insead `return of $query->result()`.

Then modify the controller:

```
public function newregistration()
{
    if ($this->form_validation->run())
    {
        $data = array(
        'UserID'=> $this->model_name->getLastInserted(),
        'Name' => $this->input->post('Name'),
        'MobileNo' => $this->input->post('MobileNo'),
        'IMEINumber' => $this->input->post('IMEINumber'),
        'City' => $this->input->post('City')
        );
        $this->adminmodel->insertregistration($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: It shows me below errors 1 - Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: models/adminmodel.php   and 2 - Column 'UserID' cannot be null in controller

Comment: public function newregistration()
 {
  $this->load->model('adminmodel');
  if ($this->form_validation->run())
  {
   $data = array(
   'UserID'=> $this->adminmodel->getLastInserted(),
   'Name' => $this->input->post('Name'),
   'MobileNo' => $this->input->post('MobileNo'),
   'IMEINumber' => $this->input->post('IMEINumber'),
   'City' => $this->input->post('City')
   );
   
  }
  }  function getLastInserted()
 {
  $query = $this->db
       ->select("MAX(`UserID`)+1 as userid")
       ->get("registerationmaster");
  return $query->result()->userid;
  
    }

Comment: change it eturn $query->result()->userid like in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

hi i worked out the solution on last inserted id dear here the code:

controller:

```
function sample() {
   $sid=$this->adminmodel->getLastInserted();
   $this->adminmodel->newregistration( $sid);
  }
```

model:

```
function getLastInserted()
  {
 $query = $query = $this->db->select('id')->order_by('id','desc')->limit(1)->get('employee_outs')->row('id');
return $query;            
}
```

model:

```
   public function newregistration($sid)
   {
     if ($this->form_validation->run())
    {
    $data = array(
    'UserID'=> $sid,
    'Name' => $this->input->post('Name'),
    'MobileNo' => $this->input->post('MobileNo'),
    'IMEINumber' => $this->input->post('IMEINumber'),
    'City' => $this->input->post('City')
    );
    $this->adminmodel->insertregistration($data);
}
  }
```